# Public key Exceeding Mod P? A Clarification Request On The Discrete Logarithm Problem

Tags: cryptography, compression, public-key-encryption, secp256k1

I tried to observe / implement the discrete logarithm problem but I noticed something about it; but before I get into it let me give some clarification which is open to correction.

> > a = b^x mod P
>
> Where as
>
> a = the public key of the address;
>
> b = the generator point of the secp256k1 koblitz curve (this is the
> curve in context);
>
> x = the discrete log;
>
> P = the modular integer.

I coupled all parameters below:

> A =
> 044f355bdcb7cc0af728ef3cceb9615d90684bb5b2ca5f859ab0f0b704075871aa385b6b1b8ead809ca67454d9683fcf2ba03456d6fe2c4abe2b07f0fbdbb2f1c1
> (uncompressed public key)
> 034f355bdcb7cc0af728ef3cceb9615d90684bb5b2ca5f859ab0f0b704075871aa :
> (compressed public key)
>
> B = 04 79BE667E F9DCBBAC 55A06295 CE870B07 029BFCDB 2DCE28D9 59F2815B
> 16F81798 483ADA77 26A3C465 5DA4FBFC 0E1108A8 FD17B448 A6855419
> 9C47D08F FB10D4B8 (uncompressed generator point)
>
> 02 79BE667E F9DCBBAC 55A06295 CE870B07 029BFCDB 2DCE28D9 59F2815B
> 16F81798 (compress generator point)
>
> X = ?
>
> P = FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE
> FFFFFC2F

I don't actually know what part of the parameters I should use ( compressed or uncompressed)

N. B :  I tried the uncompressed public key to Mod P but the uncompressed public key exceeded the Mod P in size.

What should I do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > a = b^x mod P   Where as
>
> a = the public key of the address;
>
> b = the generator point of the secp256k1 koblitz curve (this is the
> curve in context);
>
> x = the discrete log;
>
> P = the modular integer.

We are given a discrete logarithm problem (DLOG) ( also called the index calculus ); That is given `a, b,` and `P` find `x` such that `a = b^x mod P` is held. The above is actually the multiplicative notation for finite field DLOG as used by OP. ECC DLOG is additive and has different notation as;

- That is given points `A` and the base `B` find `x` such that `A = [x]B` is held on the curve E(F<sub>P</sub>). `[x]B` simply means that add the point `B` x-times to itself.

**Compression**

The beginning byte provides information about compression.

- `02` compression and choose `y`
- `03` compression and choose `-y`
- `04` No compression

To find the `y`, put the `x` into the curve equation and solve the quadratic residue by the Tonelli-Shanks algorithm.

---

In your case, both are given, no problem. Use the uncompressed public key.

The current record for secp256k1 is 114-bit On 16 June 2020 by Aleksander Zieniewic and they provided [their software](https://github.com/JeanLucPons/Kangaroo). So, if you don't have a low target, you cannot break the discrete log.

> I tried the uncompressed public key to Mod P but the uncompressed public key exceeded the Mod P in size.

A point `Q` in the Elliptic curve when used affine coordinate system it has two coordinates as `Q=(x,y)` where `x,y` from the defining field (P in your case). When checking a point Q is either on the curve or not put `x` and `y` into the curve equation `y^2 = x^3+ax+b` and check the equality.

To uncompress insert the value of `x` into the equation `x^3+ax+b mod P` to get let say value `a`, then use the Tonelli-Shanks algorithm to find the square root of `a` in this equation `y^2 = a mod P` to find `y` and `-y`. According to compression value choose `y` or `-y`.

**update per comment**

> I tried using the compressed public key but it was still bigger than mod p.

Compression a point requires information about what is the compression. Now you have given two forms of the public key `a`;

1. No compression: since the beginning starts with `04`
2. Compression but choose the `-y` since starts wiht `03`

Using capitals here not to confuse with hex `a`;

```
A = 04
4f355bdcb7cc0af728ef3cceb9615d90684bb5b2ca5f859ab0f0b704075871aa
385b6b1b8ead809ca67454d9683fcf2ba03456d6fe2c4abe2b07f0fbdbb2f1c1
```

```
A = 03
4f355bdcb7cc0af728ef3cceb9615d90684bb5b2ca5f859ab0f0b704075871aa
```

You can use the curve equation to derive the second part with chosen `-y`

And you can compare the coordinate values with

```
p = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F
a = 0x4f355bdcb7cc0af728ef3cceb9615d90684bb5b2ca5f859ab0f0b704075871aa
if a>p:
    print("a")
```

or use yours eye and mind;

```
P   = FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F
x(A)= 4f355bdcb7cc0af728ef3cceb9615d90684bb5b2ca5f859ab0f0b704075871aa
y(A)= 385b6b1b8ead809ca67454d9683fcf2ba03456d6fe2c4abe2b07f0fbdbb2f1c1
```

Comment: I'm still on this problem. I tried using the compressed public key but it was still bigger than mod p.  I think it's because when A as a point was generated, it was something like this:  A=G^x.  There was no mod p to make A fall into a finite field. But what can be done about it?

Comment: Why it should be bigger than `P`.  The EC points are pairs `(x,y)` such that `x` and `y` are in Z<sub>p</sub> and they must satisfy the curve equation.

Comment: I know right?  Here's the link to the curve parameters. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1.  Here, my A is larger than P itself. Uncompressed and compressed respectively : 044f355bdcb7cc0af728ef3cceb9615d90684bb5b2ca5f859ab0f0b704075871aa385b6b1b8ead809ca67454d9683fcf2ba03456d6fe2c4abe2b07f0fbdbb2f1c1
 034f355bdcb7cc0af728ef3cceb9615d90684bb5b2ca5f859ab0f0b704075871aa

Comment: Done. What's next?

Comment: Wow didn't see that. It's as clear as day now. Thanks.

Comment: Can you take a look at this; P = FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F A = 032834d5c5245111b414f173079ce88c496609dddf8aae5dc4ffcfa6a3dd4475af. In this example P is smaller than A

Comment: Yes, it is smaller, probably you need `a mod p`

Comment: You see, A = G ^ x mod P, which means that A should be in the range of 0 to P I.e  13 = 3 ^ 4 mod 17. So shouldn't  it be G ^ x mod P?

Comment: We are in ECC, right? Then it is `A = [x]G` and that requires scalar multiplication. And, In ECC, a point in affine coordinates has two components;`A = (x,y)`

Comment: But in Ecc, mod P's function is to limit G ^ x to the range to a certain number in 0 to P because if mod P Isn't applied then the results of G ^ x in some cases would exceed the regulations of the curve in application.

Comment: That is why I said, probably you need `mod p`. All arithmetic performed with `modulo p`. It is your task to keep them less than `p` during the operations.

Comment: A is as a result of P which means that A is to be smaller than P. Your advice is applicable when Multiplying G[x] times. The mod P is to restrict an overflow of the final value which is A.

Comment: Usually `mod p` ( I prefer to use small `p` as standard and `P` `Q` are used for the points)  is taken in every step to reduce the internal size of the values. This advice is generic, as simple you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230024/discussion-between-dave-kent-and-kelalaka).