# How to encode my Eliptic Curve Public Key to a more readable address and decode back to Public Key

Tags: javascript, encoding, elliptic-curve

I'm using an elliptic curve to generate a key pair from a bip39 seed.

```
    const EdDSA = require('elliptic').eddsa
    const ec = new EdDSA('ed25519')



    const myKey = ec.keyFromSecret(seed)
    const myPublicKey = myKey.getPublic('hex')


// output myPublicKey
// e0b1fe74117e1b95b608a4f221df314774b20ea66842350d515371c7c6966c6e
```

This is a bit long. I would like something to encode it to something shorter and add a prefix to it.

So what I have tried;

```
let address = keccak256(Buffer.from(myPublicKey, 'hex')).slice(64 - 40);
address = 'PREFIX'+address

// output
PREFIX6db2bc15fd466bda3d238ca351336a0ac2f2ea03
```

So then I want to confirm that the tx from address is derived from that user key.
I create a transaction and sing it with my key.

```
const tx = new Transaction(address, 'anotheAddress', 100);
tx.signTransaction(myKey);
```

Now I want to check if the the key own this address.

So what could I use to encode and decode this public key to something shorter?
Or is there a way I can output the key into something else than hexadecimals.

Keccak is a one way process so when the transaction get sent and need to be verified. I still need the original public key. This is where I would decode it.

Comment: Try [the compression technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66091959/1820553).

Comment: _Or is there a way I can output the key into something else than hexadecimals_ Base64 is more efficient than hex encoding (75% vs. 50%), s. [binary to text encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding).